# Evitar que cambien hora de máquina para seguir utilizando aplicación en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy terminando una aplicación en **Windows Form C#**, ahora bien, cuando implementé la parte de registrar mediante **productkey**, al cumplirse la fecha de *1 mes de prueba*, pude notar que cambiando la hora de mi máquina volvía a activarse la prueba, ¿Cómo puedo controlar eso y que el usuario no me haga este tipo de cambio?

Como pueden ver, este es el *mes actual* y le resta *1 día* para cumplirse y que no pueda seguir utilizando hasta que tenga el **productkey**.

[image]

Esta fue después de cambiar la hora manual, ahí volvió el ciclo normal para seguir utilizando la aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En este enlace de la comunidad (en inglés) hay información relacionada, espero y te sea útil: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676191/how-can-get-datetime-from-internet-external-resource-not-from-server

Answer (score 1):

Haz una peticion a `http://worldclockapi.com/` o 'http://worldtimeapi.org/', que te devuelven un JSON con la fecha actual, y ahi la almacenas o comparas para tu sistema de licencia.

Answer (score 0):

Para no pagar por un servicio en la nube donde solo vas a mostrar la fecha actual real, podes usar la librería HtmlAgilityPack

Con el siguiente código podes extraer de la pagina www.DolarHoy.com la fecha de la ultima actualización que se hizo en la pagina con el dolar.

```
        private void obtener_fecha()
    {
        string sc = Llenarhttps(); 

        // crea un documento emulando un webbrowser
        var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

        // preparo string para llenar los datos parseados 
        string wsSource; 

        wsSource = sc;
        document.LoadHtml(wsSource);

        var fecha = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div//b//span");
        MessageBox.Show(fecha[0].InnerText);
    }

    private string Llenarhttps()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.dolarhoy.com/"); // parsea la pagina
            System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            // lee todo el codigo hasta el ultimo nodo
            string sourcecode = sr.ReadToEnd();
            // trae el codigo de inicio a fin parseado
            return sourcecode; 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Ya tenes una fecha real, ahora cada vez que el usuario abra la aplicación vas a ir guardando esta información en un bloc de notas con la fecha codificada, entonces al próximo inicio el programa revisa la información y la compara con la pagina de dolarhoy si esta todo OK ahora guardara la información de la nueva fecha y conservaras la primera y así cada vez que se inicie hasta que llegara el punto que cumplirá los días y el programa no dejara que siga usándolo.

Las siguientes funciones NO ENCRIPTAN solo codifican y decodifican strings.

```
 public static string Codificar(string _cadenaAencriptar)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        byte[] encryted =
        System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(_cadenaAencriptar);
        result = Convert.ToBase64String(encryted);
        return result;
    }

    /// Esta función "desencripta" la cadena que le envíamos en el parámentro de entrada.
    public static string Decodificar(string _cadenaAdesencriptar)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        byte[] decryted =
        Convert.FromBase64String(_cadenaAdesencriptar);
        //result = 
        System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryted, 0, decryted.ToArray().Length);
        result = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryted);
        return result;
    }
```

Se me ocurrió que a su vez el bloc de notas lo guardes con un nombre codificado que tome como parámetro el serial que ingresa el usuario así se hace variable y mas difícil de rastrear para el que quiera "saltarse la seguridad".

La verdad esta es la manera mas "económica" que se me ocurrió pero estoy seguro que existen muchas mas profesionales para emplear

Saludos!

PD: Las funciones de codificado y decodificado la extraje del comentario del usuario Jorge Turrado de esta pagina 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/53f05d95-48e1-4524-9916-377ffb37f28e/mtodo-para-encriptar-y-desencriptar-contrasea?forum=winformses

Answer (score 0):

Si buscas una forma de obtener la fecha, un webservice REST una opción, este es gratis y devuelve los datos en formato JSON: http://worldclockapi.com/.
p.ej. :

```cs
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Net;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now"); // Obtiene el JSON del API REST
        System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            // lee todo el codigo hasta el ultimo nodo
            string sourcecode = sr.ReadToEnd();
            // trae el codigo de inicio a fin parseado
            //Console.WriteLine(sourcecode);
        //String resp =  "{\"$id\":\"1\",\"currentDateTime\":\"2020-02-05T22:42Z\",\"utcOffset\":\"00:00:00\",\"isDayLightSavingsTime\":false,\"dayOfTheWeek\":\"Wednesday\",\"timeZoneName\":\"UTC\",\"currentFileTime\":132254161476540563,\"ordinalDate\":\"2020-36\",\"serviceResponse\":null}";
        dynamic datos = JObject.Parse(sourcecode);
        String fechaActual = datos.currentDateTime;
        fechaActual = fechaActual.Substring(0,10);  
        Console.WriteLine(fechaActual);
    }
}
```

Para trabajar el JSON utiliza la librería JSON.NET (using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; )
Realizas la consulta antes de cargar la aplicación. Validas la fecha límite y la fecha actual.
Puedes ver un ejemplo en DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nhVSHQ

Answer (score -1):

He visto que llaman a una consulta en la nube para saber eso de los días y así el cliente si cambia la fecha no va a poder ya que es la fecha y hora de tu consulta nube.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]